# scan through FTP folder and display the contents via web

Tags: php, ftp

are there such method/programs that im able to scan through my FTP folder files and display the contents on a webpage?

apology if this seems vague, let me describe the scenario.
a user will upload to a public ftp folder, and all the contents on it, will be displayed via JSON/XML or whatever ways im able to display the files/filenames on a PHP page.

i just dont know how to phrase my question properly so i could just google it. but i opted asking here cause maybe someone could help me identify the functionality im looking for.

thanks.

Comment: Generally speaking, this sort of scenario would involve using ftp (or hopefully sftp or ftp with ssl) to upload the files to the same server as the web server is running on, and then any PHP program will just access the file system and not need to know anything about ftp. Is that the case here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **`ftp_nlist`** instead. Use below code:

```
<?php

      // set up basic connection
    $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

    // login with username and password
    $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

    // get contents of the current directory
    $contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, ".");

    // output $contents
    var_dump($contents);
    ?>
```